# How to put #foo:media(min-available-width:350px and max-available-width:750px) into SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I'm using [Element Query](https://github.com/Mr0grog/element-query) project which allows to use `@media queries` at any element. It's how it's handled:

```
#foo:media(min-available-width:350px and max-available-width:750px) {
    background:red;
}
```

But such syntax generates error (no wonder):

```
(Line 1: Invalid CSS after "...available-width": expected ")", 
was ":350px and max-...")
```

The problem is a `:` and then `space`.

How to make possible to put own syntax into SCSS files? Or how to tell preprocessor which parts of code should be left as they are? Or at least, how to make this particular piece of code work?

Other cases:

```
#foo:media(min-available-width:350px) {
    background:red;
}

#foo:media(max-available-width:750px) {
    background:red;
}

#foo .bar:media(min-available-width:350px) {
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Element Query.

You can achieve the same result with valid CSS and basic SASS:

```
#foo {
  @media (min-width:350px) {
    background:red;
  }
}
```

This results in the following CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 350px) {
  #foo {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

So there's absolutely no need to use the messy approach of Element Query.

PS Also have a look at [Breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/) and [Breakpoint Slicer](https://github.com/lolmaus/breakpoint-slicer) for better media query manipulation.

Comment: Using `Element Query` I can put `#foo` into any element on page and it will work as expected - according to available space, while your suggestion depends on view port width. Also, there is no `*-available-width` in CSS.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to do that with SASS. I like the idea behind Element Query, but its approach is very hackish and against CSS standard. Thus, lack of preprocessor support. You'll have to use a `.css` file to do that stuff.

Comment: Don't worry, be happy, uuu! I found another `Element Query`-like project: https://github.com/tysonmatanich/elementQuery which works and is compatible with CSS. But still, my question (about own syntax in SCSS) is valid.